# "Mobile" tab not visible in Free Version

Tags: mobile, app

I am new to Magento and installed mangento on my Mac system. On Admin panel , I am not able to see Mobile tab . Is this available only in paid version ? or am i missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

The new version you have downloaded from Magento does not support a Mobile App as they are now providing a responsive designed theme.